# how to implement Java socket communication on Tomcat

Tags: java, android, sockets

I currently have an TCP Java socket communication implementation in which I have a server that is listening to a port (let's say port 5478). Then I need an Android client to remotely connect to the Java server and send a SQL query, than will then be executed on the server side database and then I want to send a list of results back to the Android client (already implemented with a custom Java class named Result that implements Serializable). I do this by sending an ArrayList of Result to the Android client. The Java server is always listening to the port and supports multiple clients trough multiple Threads. How can I migrate this implementation to a more secure platform and what is the best way to do it? I don't need to respect HTTP protocol to afford this communication. Is Tomcat the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Servlet3.0 as part of tomcat.

Then from android you just have to send http requests to the server using a URL and the servlet can database them. You can also serialize the data as well if you need to.

I hope that answers your question.

~ Dan

//EDIT:

Once you have set up eclipse and tomcat, you can start writing servlets. First - you have to configure the server to use servlets for certain addresses, for example localhost:8080/myServlet - that means that anything you send to local host triggers the servlet. The code for your first servelet looks like this:

```
public class ExampServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
  {
```

Your doPost method is what gets called when you perform a http post request on the address the servlet is listening on. Then, all you have to do it put some code in to read the request to get the data out of the message body. Basically you read your request object that gets passed in, and you write to your response object to send the response back to the client. There are plenty of guides out there. I followed something like this to get started:

http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Hope that helps :)

~ Dan

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any clue on how the servlet can extract the usefull information from the client http request?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is an Servlet container + webserver. If you plan to move to tomcat then you are implicitly moving to http. And yes, if you want a secure communication .. you can create a soap based webservice(apache axis) and host it on https.

Comment: Thanks. I see there are multiple ways of making this. My client actually only needs to send plain text, like Strings. Those strings are then translated to SQL on the server side. I will look forward to http communication adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how mutch additional security tomcat is able to provide for your application. Two tings come to mind:

1. Enforcing authentication and some access rules. This is not too hart to implement and heavily depends on the rule quality. However it may help f you use it. It's often replaced by own imlpementations. However, to get securty you need encryption i.e. https. Or it's possible to steel the session and gain the rights bound to it.
2. Request to file mapping. This in fact somewhat more complicated. You shouldn't code this on your own. It's more complicated than it looks at first sight.

However, one of the biggest security wholes ever is directly executing code you got from somewhere. For example SQL statements. Ok it's secure as long as your databse rights are set perfectly...
Developing a securly encrypted protocol is not simple either.
However, the major win on switching to tomcat (or whatever) might be scaleability for free. And I think implementing servlets is much simpler than programming against sockets. And there are many great to tools fo working with http(s) though ven it might be more complicated than yours, it's pretty simple to deal with.

Unfortunately I can't answer our question. I don't know what's the best solution is. But I think there's at least some potential for wins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I at least will try to implement SSL (which guarantees integrity) and HTTP POST messages to send data from the client to the server. Thanks